# Using Oracle SQL (PL/SQL) to create a distributed database

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, distributed

I have to create a distributed database using Oracle PL/SQL but I am not sure where to start and can't find any tutorial on it. It's for a lab so it's all in a local environment where I'll have 3 VMs spun up on a machine. We are using this pre-built VM: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/databaseappdev-vm.html

Comment: There are a lot of tutorials suitable to guide you in this matter on the web. Just google it!

Comment: @Rodrigo Can you point me to one? I can't seem to find any when Googling it.

Comment: Sure thing!

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/plsql/index.htm
https://www.guru99.com/pl-sql-tutorials.html
https://www.oracletutorial.com/plsql-tutorial/
.
Videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3cG1pCglUE

.
If you are familiar with docker, I've created an Oracle XE 11g image and maybe would be helpful.

https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/rodrigoraraujo/oraclexe

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of scope in what you mean by a "distributed database". It could mean

- database links to communicate between them
- REST
- a queue infrastucture using AQ

so it really depends on what you are after.  But assuming database links, then the first thing is to know the network mechanism for connecting a remote database. For example, if you can do:

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@some_other_database
```

then this means that "some_other_database" is defined in your $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/tnsnames.ora file.  That means that *within* your database, you can now do:

```
SQL> create database link blah
2 connect to scott
3 identified by tiger
4 using 'some_other_database'
5 /

Database link created.

SQL> select * from dual@blah;
```

The "blah" will connect to the "some_other_database" using the SCOTT username and password and access the remote database from this current one.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing why you have to use PL/SQL and what your requirements are all I can suggest looking into Oracle Active Data Guard and/or Oracle GoldenGate. Both these products are rock solid if you need to distribute your loads.

I presume you actually need some CDC (change data capture) functionality?

Here is a summary of them both:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/availability/dataguardgoldengate-096557.html

ADG is good for distributing read loads but GG can do multi - way synchronization for a completely distributed load.

As long this is for development / education I believe the software is free of use.

Making a custom CDC in PL/SQL is not fun if you want something dynamic and fast. I have done/tried this once many years ago. It got more and more complicated.